# Creating a template for a brand during an interview?

Tags: jobs, interview

I'm pretty deep in the interview, but the interviewer is asking me to create a template that represents their brand. I honestly haven't heard of this before. Is anyone familiar with doing something like this?

Comment: What does building a template mean? Is it showing your layout skills? Coding skills? Graphic design skills?

Comment: This is a question that you should put to the interviewer. They'll expect (and probably want) you to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building your requirements you have to be aware if your user is more of visual or non-visual person. In your case, your client is more comfortable of visual presentation then you have to draft your design model through sets of wireframes containing most of the prescribe content in general. Just keep in mind your crafting the low fidelity and not to be over detailed. Iterate and be consistent throughout your process until you get to mid fidelity and finally to high fidelity before starting on your prototype or mockup model.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a template means (either website with their company brand and title which contains related information to their brand OR PSD(Photoshop) design using tool and add Brand related things). it depends on the Profile,to using HTML,CSS,Javascript (Website template) OR using Photoshop PSD Template